# Classic asp radiobutton groups get values

Tags: asp-classic, postback, radio-button

Is there a way to iterate radio groups on a form post to do something with each radio button group? I have a varying number of radio button sets and need to get values and id's out of each of them on a postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but it might point you in the right direction. If you prefix all names of your radio buttons with "rb" (or some other prefix of your choosing), then the following should give you access to each radio button on a post:

```
for x = 1 to Request.Form.count() 
    if(Left(Request.Form.key(x),2) = "rb") then
        Response.Write(Request.Form.key(x) & " = " & Request.Form.item(x) & "<br/>") 
    end if
next
```